# Реакция на позицию select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Это часть кода, задача кода - при выборе select создавать дополнительное поле в которое вписывается дополнительный параметр. Для одного файла все работает, но для нескольких работает уже не правильно. Далее с помощью массива идет сортировка и запись в бд.

```js
$("#type_item").on('change', function(){
    if(($(this).val() == 2)||($(this).val() == 4)){
        $("#num_material").show();
       $("#num_material").prop('required', true);
    } else {
        $("#num_material").hide();
     $("#num_material").prop('required', false);
    }
})
$(".file_size").each(function () {
  var $wrapper = $(".file_sizes", this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
    $(".file_sizes_list:first-child", $wrapper)
      .clone(true)
      .appendTo($wrapper)
      .find("input")
      .val("")
      .focus();
  });
  $(".file_sizes_list .remove-field", $wrapper).click(function () {
    if ($(".file_sizes_list", $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent(".file_sizes_list").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
<div class="file_size">
  <div class="file_sizes">
    <div class="file_sizes_list">
   <input id="name_file" type="text" name="name[]" >  
    <select name="type_item[]" id="type_item">
        <option value="1">Первый пункт</option>
        <option value="2">Второй пункт</option>
        <option value="3">Третий пункт</option>
        <option value="4">Четвертый пункт</option>
    </select>
    <input id="num_material" type="text" name="input[]" style="display:none">
  <button type="button" class="remove-field">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Добавить поле</button>
</div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в том, что добавленные поля имеют такой же name и id, как и первое поле. Попробуйте реализовать так, чтобы, к примеру, id имел вид id="name_file_1" и каждый последующий имел другой номер: name_file_2, name_file_3 и т.д.

Comment: Это я понял, вопрос какой цикл теперь поставить и как отслеживать индексы.